# How to set up ChatJS with ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-4.0, chatjs

i just want to set up [ChatJs](http://www.chatjs.net/) with asp.net 4.0. i read all steps that provided with it's documentation. but i can't install to my application.

here my web application built with 4.0 framework. so may be this chatjs support greater version with 4.5. Is there any body know how i install this chat application with asp.net 4.0 with sql server 2008.
i successfully set up all basic files like chatjs and signalR to my web app but here at startup.cs file gives some compile time error.

here is my startup.cs file code :

```
using ChatJs.Admin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace ChatJs.Admin
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            this.ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my compile time errors:

```
Error   1   'ChatJs.Admin.Startup' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureAuth' and no extension method 'ConfigureAuth' accepting a first argument of type 'ChatJs.Admin.Startup' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\EasyWeb\App_Code\Startup.cs  11  18  F:\EasyWeb\

Error   2   'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'MapSignalR' and no extension method 'MapSignalR' accepting a first argument of type 'Owin.IAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   F:\EasyWeb\App_Code\Startup.cs  12  17  F:\EasyWeb\
```

please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### About the absense of the `ConfigureAuth` method:

You are refering to this call:

https://github.com/ChatJS/ChatJs-Demo/blob/master/ChatJs.Admin/Startup.cs#L17

The reason why it's apparently missing is because Microsoft determined that the best place to put all the ASP.NET startup code is in the App_Start folder, so there's a partial class for Startup there. The ConfigureAuth method is here:

https://github.com/ChatJS/ChatJs-Demo/blob/master/ChatJs.Admin/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L11

### About the absense of the MapSignalR method:

The `MapSignalR` method is defined in the class `OwinExtensions` from the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core` assembly. This is specific to SignalR and it will only run on .NET 4.5.

### Running ChatJS 2.0 in the .NET Framework 4.0

ChatJS 2.0 will run on .NET 4.0, but only if you reference SignalR 1 instead of 2. There's no reason why ChatJS uses SignalR 2 appart from it being the latest version. Please notice that Microsoft changed the way SignalR is initialized from version 1 to 2 so the SignalR part of the tutorial won't apply.